# Error when compiling with ANTLR in Visual C# Express 2010

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to build an application in C# that parses (using ANTLR) a C source file and returns me an AST with all the functions and stuff.

I did what was explained here : http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=557075#
But after doing all that when I try and compile I get the following errors:
The type or namespace name 'GrammarRuleAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have antlr-3.4 and antlrworks-1.4.3.jar
I've used the dll that are in the \antlr-3.4\runtime\CSharp2\dist\DOT-NET-runtime-3.1.3.zip and just noticed now that they are supposed to be for ANTLR 3.1.3

What could cause my problem, I must say I'm a bit lost so many versions

Comment: Posted here as well: http://antlr.markmail.org/message/uoe4ibquxrb7twtz

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412684/antlr-3-4-c-sharp-the-type-or-namespace-name-grammarrule-could-not-be-found The answer given in thread Bart pointed out is of no use, I have VS Ultimate and it does not make any difference. It is not about extensions after all but simply compiling C# code. Anyway, same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. using the runtime libs provided [here](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3CSharpReleases) and CSharp3 target with antlr 3.4 worked for me. the problem is that the runtime libs comming with antlr-3.4 for CSharp2 target are out of date. i did not try, but maybe building the runtime libs from source is another option that could help.