# ANTLR 3.4, c# The type or namespace name 'GrammarRule' could not be found

Tags: c#, antlr

That's it. I have correct grammar file (or I can just take example from ANTLR site) and after code generation I get this in my Visual Studio 2010.

Runtime is already in references:
 - antlr.runtime.dll
 - Antlr3.Runtime.dll
 - Antlr3.Utility
 - StringTemplate

Any workaround or, maybe, ideads?

- ANTLR 3.4 (language = CSharp2)
- C# 4.0